# table with 200.000+ records taking 4 seconds select

Tags: mysql

I have a table `following` where one user can follow another.
This table has 200.000+ records. and my select is taking a while.

```
where (p.user in (select following from following where user =1 and block=0 and feed=0) or p.user=1) and p.delete='0'
```

I have this `where` to get `users` that `user=1` follows. This is the parte that is taking longer.

my following table:

```
`following` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  `following` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  `block` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `feed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`user`, `following`)
)
```

any ideas how to get followings faster and improve this table? any ideas of index or anything?

my full sql:

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2 

from posts p 

join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = ?

where (p.user in (select following from following where user =? and block=0) or p.user=?) and p.delete='0'

group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

posts:

```
  KEY `share` (post_share, `delete`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can we get an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) on this select as well?

Comment: @JNevill I've just added it!

Comment: Is there an index on `posts.user` or `following.user`? It doesn't seem like it from the explain and I would think that would help quite a lot here. Potentially also `likes.post` and then possibly `comentarios.foto`

Comment: thanks friend! I think I don't have index on users. I'll try to add it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking to pull up only `following.block=0`.  On your `following` table it looks like you should have an index for `(user, following, block)` this would make it an index only scan.

It is important to get rid of that nested query.

Here's a guess but I believe you're looking for the following:

```
select c.nome,
 p.foto,
 c.user,
 p.user,
 p.id,
 p.data,
 p.titulo,
 p.youtube,
 pp.foto,
 count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count,
 count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, 
 count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2 

from posts p 

    join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
    left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
    left join likes on likes.post = p.id
    left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
    left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = ?

    left join following f on f.user = p.user

where 
(p.user = ? and p.delete = '0')
or 
(f.user = ? and f.block=0)

group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

Comment: That could be an `INNER JOIN` to `following` which may improve query performance.