# query takes 0.0005 seconds but when using as subquery it increase the select to 2.+

Tags: mysql

I have this select:

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2

from posts p 

join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = 1

where (p.user in (select following from following where user =1 and block=0 and feed=0) or p.user=1) and p.delete='0'
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit 15
```

it usually takes 2.2705 seconds.
If I remove the `(p.user in (select following from following where user =1 and block=0 and feed=0) or p.user=1) and` it will take 0.0018

If I use the select below it will take just 0.0005 seconds:

```
select following from following where user =1 and block=0 and feed=0
```

My question here is, what am I doing wrong? one first query runs in 0.0018 and second in 0.0005 = 0.0023. why my full select is taking 2.2705? what is the logic here?

Comment: What makes you think you're doing anything wrong?

Comment: have you tried running an `explain` on the query?

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong. The IN operator will have to compare if each p.user is in the selection, which increases the total time.

Comment: is this question related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255021/table-with-200-000-records-taking-4-seconds-select ?

Comment: to add to @tk3 's comment a  `... IN (SELECT ... )` statement can be better rewritten as a `... INNER JOIN .. ON ...` statement..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried: `INNER JOIN following f ON f.user = '1' and p.user = f.following` but the time was the same. 2.+

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then, please [edit] your question to give us more information.

Comment: I don't think INNER JOIN is right here, since it must match if user is  IN the subquery's result set OR if user = 1

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the time. The IN operator will have to verify if each p.user is present in the *N* elements returned by the selection, which naturally increases the total time.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this answer so you also have a cleaner way to do it :

```
SELECT c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2
FROM posts p 
JOIN cadastro c ON p.user=c.id 
LEFT JOIN profile_picture pp ON p.user = pp.user
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.post = p.id
LEFT JOIN comentarios ON comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
LEFT JOIN likes l2 ON l2.post = p.id and l2.user = 1
LEFT JOIN following f ON f.following = p.user AND f.user = 1 AND f.block = 0 AND f.feed = 0
WHERE (f.following IS NOT NULL OR p.user=1) AND p.delete = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 15
```